# How to pass textbox from view to it's own controller again and again?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, textbox

What I'm trying to do is to pass the value of the textbox of this certain view to it's own controller.

The view has only 1 textbox, the textbox for id , then the controller has linq query that search the database that match that id.

So when I run my program , first it would show empty gridview and empty textbox. What I want to do is when I input a text in the textbox and press submit , it would call it's own controller and pass the value of the textbox that contains the id so the linq query will have something to use so it can display a search result.

Did I make sense ? :0 sorry I'm a just a beginner.

Comment: u can use ajax call and load a partial view to fill ur grid with filtered data...

Comment: can you be more specific ? perhaps an example would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that Text box value using form Collection, Foe Ex,your view may look like this

```
@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("controllerName","ActionName",FormMethod.Post)) 
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Movie</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.TextBox("Name",null,New {id="Name"})
    </div>

<div class="editor-label">
        <input type="submit" value="save" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
}

In controller,
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult MethodName(FormCollection form)
{
string name = form["Name"];

// name contains your textbox value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
database acces ? 

query; 

OleDbDataReader readername;
OleDbCommand commandname = new OleDbCommand("Select textBox1.Text=@"+textBox1.Text+" from tablename",connectionname);

connectionname.Open();
readername = commandname.ExecuteReader();
while (readername.Read()) //the result
{
label1.Text = readername[textbox1.Text].ToString(); 
}
connectionname.Close();
```

Comment: Code only answers, which may well be a workable solution, are usually improved by some explanation. Please consider commenting or explaining how your suggested code works.